# ¿como crear un árbol mediante dos vectores de manera recursiva java?

Tags: java, array, recursión, vectores, tree

Hola espero me puedan ayudar, lo que pasa es que estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el cual creo un arbol binario de busqueda mediante dos recorridos que me da un usuario, con las siguiente reglas
uno de los dos recorridos debe ser el recorrido inOrden y debe ser recursivo.
Yo hago el siguiente algoritmo para crearlo

```
public static void crearArbol(Comparable elem1[], Comparable elem2[], Arbol ObjetoArbol, int pos1, int pos2) {
    if(pos1 != elem1.length - 1 || pos2 != elem2.length - 1) {
        if(elem1[pos1].compareTo(elem2[pos2]) == 0) {
            ObjetoArbol.insertar(elem1[pos1]);

            System.out.print("  "+elem1[pos1]+"  ");
            crearArbol(elem1, elem2, ObjetoArbol, pos1 + 1, 0);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("  ");
            crearArbol(elem1, elem2, ObjetoArbol, pos1, pos2 + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

pero me salta un error de superar el tamaño del vector

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:113)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:119)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:119)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:119)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:119)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:119)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:119)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.crearArbol(Prueba.java:124)
    at Presentacion.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:35)
```

creo que me falta una validación pero no tengo idea en donde la tengo que hacer ayuda por favooor es para un proyecto muy importante.

Answer (score 0):

En el condicional del primer `if`, donde compruebas los tamaños de los vectores con las variables `pos1` y `pos2`. Estás usando un *or* (`||`), en lugar de un *and* (`&&`).

Por lo cual, cuando cualquiera de esas condiciones se cumpla se entra. Por ejemplo, `pos1` podría ser 0, y estar bien, y `pos2` podría ser 100000 y fuera del rango, pero como `pos1` cumple la condición, entra en el `if` y entonces te salta el error.

Prueba con:
`if((pos1 != (elem1.length - 1)) && (pos2 != (elem2.length - 1)))`

Por otro lado, una sugerencia para simplificar: Yo usaría `< length` en lugar de `!= length - 1`

`if((pos1 < elem1.length) && (pos2 < elem2.length))`